# joomla returning invalid fields for user registration

Tags: user, custom-field, registration, fields, user-registration

I've added in custom fields for joomla registration, however it's returning them as Invalid Fields?

```
$requestData = $this->input->post->get('jform', array(), 'array');
echo '<pre>';print_r($requestData);echo '</pre>';

Array
(
    [name] => testing
    [username] => testing
    [password1] => testing
    [password2] => testing
    [email1] => testing@testing.com
    [email2] => testing@testing.com
    [com_fields] => Array
        (
            [country] => Australia
            [australian-state] => Victoria
            [are-you-a] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Pre-service teacher
                )

            [how-did-you-hear-about-forestlearning] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Schools association
                )

        )

)

Invalid field: Country *
Invalid field: Australian State
Invalid field: Are you a *
```

These are fields I have added into Users -> Fields, and display fine on the form. Any ideas?

Joomla version 3.9.18

Comment: Thank you for linking your Stack Exchange accounts -- I don't know when you did that, but once upon a time they were unassociated.  I hope that we will see you at a future Australian JUG Meetup.  MJUG doesn't currently have their [future events](https://www.meetup.com/melbournejug/events/) listed, but our Brissie Meetup shows [the next few Zoom Meetup dates](https://www.meetup.com/Joomla-Users-Group-Brisbane/events/) -- no topics announced yet, but always the 3rd Tuedays of every month and open to all.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it was the permissions for each new profile field, I set them to be allowed and it now saves.

Comment: This answer was auto-flagged by the system for being low-quality based on its length/content.  Could you perhaps expand on this answer to articulate exactly what you did to remedy the issue?  A screenshot?  Link to documentation?  There will surely be less experienced Joomla users who would appreciate a more generous answer.  Cheers.